# Meteor prevent template from rendering depending on a condition

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a situation in which the user is redirected to a template (say I ). 
In template I, there is a condition which would determine if we should render that template or redirect to some other place.

The way I am doing right now is to check for that condition in the `Template.I.onCreated()` and if that condition is true, then putting `window.location.href` to the new url.

But this is sometimes causing the template I to appear briefly on screen before redirection.

I need a way to be able to stop this from happening. I thought onCreated() fires before onRendered() so it should have prevented that. But still this does not seem to work.

Comment: Better to do this in the router

Comment: @MichelFloyd is correct - it would be preferable to let the router control this instead of manually changing the window location. Could you describe your condition that you are checking?

Comment: @MichelFloyd I don't want to use router because the page that is being redirected to is in a new template which has some scripts in it which don't load till I reload the page completely. It seems Iron router does not let us run scripts embedded in template fragments(is it?)

Comment: Are you trying to use external scripts? In a single page app you should never need to "reload" any page, that implies something is broken.

Comment: I sense an XY problem. What are you really trying to do? What scripts are you expecting to run? And again what's the condition you would be checking against to redirect?

Comment: @MichelFloyd my problem is that the meteor project is already setup and we have two templates. Client's new theme is totally incompatiable(in terms of css selectors etc.) with the old theme. Some pages have to be in old theme and others in new theme.

That's why I have those external scripts specific to the other theme pages.

Comment: @ᴄʜaᴢsᴏʟᴏ i worked to fix it using Iron router's `onBeforeAction` which works well. Why i am using external scripts is in my previous comment

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to conditionally render a template in blaze is to wrap it with an `{{# if}}`:

```
<template name="parentTemplate">
{{#if someCondition}}
  {{> childTemplate }}
{{/if}}
</template>
```

You can define a helper in js that returns a truthy or falsy value for `someCondition`. No need to do anything in `onCreated`.

Changing the url via `window.location.href` is highly discouraged. This will cause the entire app to be reloaded, including all the subscriptions.

Comment: I fixed using your suggestion in comments for Iron router's onBeforeAction.

You can update your answer accordingly and I am gonna accept with an upvote :)

Comment: That one belongs to @chazsolo!